# Help to display the current categories and tags of a post

Tags: categories, shortcode, tags

I am using a shortcode to **try** to display the tags and categories of a post.
Specifically, this is a portfolio post, so when a user visits a post they will see the associated categories and tags. [example here](https://marceau.qodeinteractive.com/portfolio-item/better-industry/)

My shortcode is pulling **all** portfolio-categorys or portfolio-tags, not just those of the current post.

```
<?php
class ListCategories{
  static function list_categories($atts, $content = null) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
      array(
        'child_of'            => 0,
        'current_category'    => 0,
        'depth'               => 0,
        'echo'                => 1,
        'exclude'             => '',
        'exclude_tree'        => '',
        'feed'                => '',
        'feed_image'          => '',
        'feed_type'           => '',
        'hide_empty'          => 1,
        'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
        'hierarchical'        => 1,
        'include'             => '',
        'number'              => null,
        'order'               => 'ASC',
        'orderby'             => 'name',
        'pad_counts'          => 0,
        'show_count'          => 0,
        'show_option_all'     => '',
        'show_option_none'    => __( 'No categories' ),
        'style'               => 'list',
        'taxonomy'            => 'category',
        'title_li'            => __( 'Categories' ),
        'use_desc_for_title'  => 1,
        'walker'              => null,
      ), $atts
    );

    ob_start();
    wp_list_categories($atts);
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;
  }
}

add_shortcode( 'categories', array('ListCategories', 'list_categories') );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default `category` and `post_tag` taxonomies for your portfolio posts, then have a look at [`get_the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/) and [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/). These will return arrays of tags and categories for the current post. Pass post ID as parameter to the functions, when using outside the Loop.

If on the other hand you have custom taxonomies, then use [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) directly, for which you can pass the custom taxonomy slug as the 2nd parameter, post ID being the 1st.

If you want to use `wp_list_categories()`, then you should pass `include` as one of the parameters so that the list is limited to the given term IDs. There's a [nice example on the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/#comment-1169) how to do this with the help of `wp_get_object_terms()`.

Comment: The category taxonomy is portfolio-category.
And the posts are portfolio-tag.
I assume those are custom taxonomies created by the theme I'm customizing.

Comment: @Georgeand Yes, I would assume so too.